# Grouping Minus Oracle Problems

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I've just created this query and I get confuse by the time I grouping this because I can't see them as one grouping. This query runs but not the way I wanted, I want to group the query by the team name but the problem occurs when its query being counted using count(*) and the result of its counting produces the same number ,,,

```
  SELECT TEAM.NAMATEAM, PERSONAL.KODEPERSON
    FROM TEAM,  PERSONAL
   WHERE TEAM.KODETEAM = PERSONAL.KODETEAM
GROUP BY PERSONAL.KODEPERSON, TEAM.NAMATEAM

MINUS 

  SELECT TEAM.NAMATEAM, PERSONAL.KODEPERSON
    FROM TEAM, PERSONAL, AWARD_PERSON 
   WHERE TEAM.KODETEAM = PERSONAL.KODETEAM 
     AND AWARD_PERSON.PEMENANG = PERSONAL.KODEPERSON
GROUP BY TEAM.NAMATEAM, PERSONAL.KODEPERSON;
```

I want to group all these using the team name but using counting will be problem since I have no idea to group within the technique that can be run smoothly as I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to achieve, i.e. what result set do you want? All the teams who have never obtained an award?

Comment: Thanks for comment, already solved by the user below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I understand your question? You are trying to make a table of columns NAMATEAM,X where NAMATEAM are the team names, and X are the number of people on each team who do not have awards (listed in AWARD_PERSON). If so, you should be able to use a sub-select:

```
SELECT T_NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT TEAM.NAMATEAM "T_NAME", PERSONAL.KODEPERSON
    FROM TEAM, PERSONAL
    WHERE TEAM.KODETEAM = PERSONAL.KODETEAM
    MINUS
    SELECT TEAM.NAMATEAM "T_NAME", PERSONAL.KODEPERSON
    FROM TEAM, PERSONAL, AWARD_PERSON
    WHERE TEAM.KODETEAM = PERSONAL.KODETEAM 
    AND AWARD_PERSON.PEMENANG = PERSONAL.KODEPERSON )
    -- your original query without the GROUP BYs
GROUP BY T_NAME
```

The first subselect SELECT creates a full list of players, the second subselect SELECT creates a list of players who have won awards (I assume), the MINUS removes the award winners from the full list. Thus the full subselect returns a list of players and their teams, for all players without awards.

The main SELECT then summarizes on the team name only, to yield a per-team count of players without awards.

You should not need your original GROUP BY TEAM.NAMATEAM, PERSONAL.KODEPERSON, unless you have duplicate rows in your database, e.g., one player on one team has more than one row in the database.

Comment: select * from 
(
select distinct team.namateam as team, sum(match_list.scorehome) "nomor" from team, match_list
where match_list.home = team.kodeteam
UNION 
select distinct team.namateam as team, sum(match_list.scoreaway) "nomor" from team, match_list
where match_list.away = team.kodeteam
)a
group by a.team;

Can you fix this?

Comment: In the sub-SELECTs, remove the `DISTINCT`s so that the whole sub-select returns one row (TEAM,NOMOR) for each match played, home or away. Then use main SELECT to summarize by team with `SELECT TEAM, SUM(NOMOR) FROM ( ... ) GROUP BY TEAM`. Hope this helps.